# Which kind of derivative give $D e^{xy}=e^{xy}$?

Tags: calculus

Which kind of derivative give $D e^{xy}=e^{xy}$? Or any insight why if  such derivative not exist? Also explain **$D e^{{x}^{y}}=e^{{x}^{y}}$** if you want.

Comment: $$\frac{d(e^z)}{dz}=e^z,$$ set $z=xy$

Comment: @bhattacharjee slope from z axis?

Answer (score 0):

Try
$$
D=\frac1{2y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac1{2x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.
$$